# django: sort table data according to other table data

Tags: sql, django

I have read the (excellent) documentation but I can't figure out how
to do this.

I have a table which represents user friendships called
"Shortlist" (with fields "from_user" and "to_user": both Foreign Keys to the
classic auth_user table. Namely, from_user befriends to_user).

I have another table into which I log user events/actions (UserLog).
In this table there are many fields including a "timestamp" and of
course a "user" field (a foreign key to the auth_user
table)

how can I retrieve data from table "Shortlist" for a specific user
(from_user) ordered by the timestamp in UserLog table? Or how can I
retrieve Shortlist data for a specific from_user ordered by the total
number of "to_user" actions logged?

in other words I would like to retrieve all user's friends that are
most active or order them by most recent action first.

---

thanks for your answer, however I think I might need some more help. What I want to do is to order users according to their activity (most active user first). Activities are logged in another table.

for instance I want to do something like this (if possible)

select * from Users U, (select count (id) from UserLog L where U.id=L.user_id) as actions order by actions desc

I would also like to sort them according to their latest actions (user whith most recent action, first)

any ideas (or best practices) on how to do those things?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Orderring  by another table is possible with related field syntax:

Example:

```
UserProfile.objects.all().order_by('user__username')
```

To calculate thing based on fields use [annotations](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#filtering-on-annotations)

Comment: Do note that when using `order_by` with other tables you might get duplicate rows in some cases. To counteract that behaviour you need to call `distinct()` on the queryset.

Comment: I want to do the same task but I don't have foreign key to the other table.

Comment: I want to do this, but the table that I have a foreign key to exists in another database and so cannot be joined.  Any advice?